# How to read the subkeys in registry

Tags: nsis

Hi I have the registry structure like below

```
HKLM
    SOFTWARE
        MYAPP
            VER1
            VER2
            VER3
```

like that list goes depending on how many patches I install on top of MYAPP. Now I want read VER1, VER2 ... and I want to capture last VERX. How can read the subkeys under MYAPP and find out last subkey.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer - how to read registry keys (not values).

From [NSIS Scripting Reference](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html)

**4.9.2.5 EnumRegKey**

```
user_var(output) root_key subkey index
```

> Set user variable $x with the name of the 'index'th registry key in
>   root_key\Subkey. Valid values for root_key are listed under
>   WriteRegStr. Returns an empty string if there are no more keys, and
>   returns an empty string and sets the error flag if there is an error.

```
StrCpy $0 0
loop:
  EnumRegKey $1 HKLM Software $0
  StrCmp $1 "" done
  IntOp $0 $0 + 1
  MessageBox MB_YESNO|MB_ICONQUESTION "$1$\n$\nMore?" IDYES loop
done:
```

In your case:

```
EnumRegKey $1 HKLM "Software\MYAPP" $0
```